# Determining if the following sets are subspaces or not

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was hoping someone could verify if my reasoning was correct on these questions to see if the following sets $(B_i)$ are subspaces of the corresponding vector space $(V_i)$ or not.

> $V_1=P_2, B_1=\{p \in P_2|p+xp' \text{ has degree exactly 2}\}.\text{($p'$ is the he derivative of $p$).}$

I think this one IS a vector space.

the polynomial is essentially $ax^2+bx+c+x(2ax+b)$.

This implies that we have $ax^2+(b+2a)x+(c+b)$.

Now, I set $b+2a=\alpha$ and $c+b=\beta$.

So this way, I have $ax^2+\alpha x+\beta$.

**Zero vector**:

This clearly exists if I set $a=0$, $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=0$.

**Closure under addition**:

Suppose I have $ax^2+\alpha x+\beta$ and $dx^2+\gamma x+\theta$.

This would mean that $(ax^2+\alpha x+\beta)$+$(dx^2+\gamma x+\theta)$ gives $fx^2+gx+h$ if I define $a+d=f$, $\alpha + \gamma = g$ and $\beta + \theta = h$.

So we have closure under addition.

**Closure under scalar multiplication**:

Here, I take $ax^2+\alpha x+\beta$ and multiply by some constant $k$. This means I have:

$k(ax^2+\alpha x+\beta)$ or $lx^2+m x+n$ which means I have closure under scalar multiplication.

So $B_1$ is indeed a subspace.

> $V_2 = M_2(\mathbb{R}), B_2=\{X \in M_2{\mathbb(R)|XA=0}, \text{where } A= \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 2 & 3\\
> 4 & 5 & 6
> \end{pmatrix}$

**Zero vector**:

If I set the entries in $X$ to $0$, then $XA=0$ so thus, the zero vector is satisfied.

**Closure under addition**:

If I define an element $X_1$ and $X_2$, then $(X_1 + X_2)A=(X_1*A+X_2*A)=0+0=0$ so we have closure under addition.

**Closure under scalar multiplication**:

If I define a constant $c|c \in \mathbb{R}$, then we have $c(XA)$. However, $XA=0$, so we have $c(0)=0$ so we have closure under addition.

So $B_2$ is indeed a subspace.

> $V_3=S, B_3=\{(a_n)_n \in S|a_n = a^2_{n-1} \text{ for all } n\geq 1\}.$

**Zero vector**:

If $n \geq 1$, then I define $a_0=0$ and $a_1=0$ so that I have $0=0^2$ or $0=0$. So the zero vector exists.

**Closure under addition**:

$a_n+b_n = a^2_{n-1} + b^2_{n-1}$ which implies that $c_n = c^2_{n-1}$. So the vector space is closed under scalar addition.

**Closure under scalar multiplication**:

$c*a_n = c*a^2_{n-1}$ implies $d_n = d^2_{n-1}$.

So we have closure under scalar multiplication.

Therefore, $B_3$ is a subspace.

> $V_4 = F, B_4 = \{ f \in F|f(0)=f(1) \}$

This is one I am not sure about. I think the zero vector exists since I could just define $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=0$ but I am not sure how I would show addition or scalar multiplication.

In a follow up, is this even a subspace in the first place? I can't tell.

If someone could verify if my reasoning is correct on the first three sets and explain the 4th set a little more, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $\mathbf 0(x)$ is the zero polynomial, then $\mathbf 0'(x) + x\mathbf 0(x) = 0$, and this has no degree exactly $2$.
- Fine!
- Closed under addition means that if $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ are two sequences of real numbers such that $a_n = a_{n-1}^2$ and $b_n = b_{n-1}^2$ for all $n \geq 1$, then $a_n+b_n = (a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})^2$ for all $n \geq 1$. So...
- If $\mathbf0$ is the zero function, then $\mathbf0(0) = 0 = \mathbf0(1)$, which means $\mathbf0 \in B_4$. Similarly, if $f,g \in B_4$ and $c$ is a real number, then $(cf+g)(0) = cf(0)+g(0) = cf(1)+g(1) = (cf+g)(1)$, which means $cf+g \in B_4$.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that restriction in part a. 

For part c, I forgot the elements themselves have to be added and THEN squared rather than adding the squared elements since you're checking if addition hold for the given condition for all elements.

Thanks for the hint about part d! That clears up the rest of it.